# FragmentStateAdapter detaching and pausing fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a FragmentStateAdapter with a ViewPager2 in my Android app, and I've noticed that the adapter is detaching and pausing my fragments when I swipe to a different item, even though I've overridden the adapter's onDetachedFromRecyclerView() method to do nothing.

Here's the relevant code from my adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    // constructor and other methods...

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        // Do nothing to keep fragment's view hierarchy intact
    }
}
```

Despite this code, I'm still seeing onPause() being called on my fragments when I swipe to a different item. I've checked for other lifecycle events that might be causing the fragments to pause, and I've also made sure that offscreenPageLimit is set to other values like 2 because I have 2 fragments. I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue.

Any ideas on what might be going on, or how I can prevent my fragments from being paused? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager2 does not 'detach' fragments at all. However, it **does** ensure that only the current screen is `RESUMED` - other fragments are capped at the `STARTED` state (this is how individual fragments can tell if they are the currently selected screen). This mirrors the same behavior of ViewPager1 in its [`BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT()). You can verify this if you are using ViewPager2 1.1 releases as it [`onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.FragmentTransactionCallback#onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State)) callback is called whenever this behavior kicks in.

There's no way to turn this off or change this behavior as this is the expected behavior of ViewPager2.

You should absolutely **not ever** override `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` and not call `super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView` as all that does is cause a memory leak within `FragmentStateAdapter` as it is not able to unregister its own listeners tied to the RecyclerView.